# Subscribe to Outlook notifications from a web add-In (Office js)

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

I am developing a web add-in for Outlook as an extension to our meetings management web-app. The problem is that we need to know when the user changes the date of a meeting in Outlook (without opening our add-in), so that we can take the necessary actions within our system.

I have looked into subscriptions and Microsoft Graph, but just can't seem to find anywhere an explanation or tutorial on how to implement it using JavaScript and Office js.

It would be of great help if someone could guide me through the basic steps, or link to an external resource/tutorial that explains the process.

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to know of a change in meeting date outside the add-in context?

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT Yes I specifically want to know when a user drags an event from one date to another inside the calendar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but web add-ins do not currently support this capability. It is not possible to listen to changes in meeting start and end dates without explicitly running the add-in.

If the add-in is already opened, you can use the [AppointmentTimeChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/objectmodel/requirement-set-1.7/office.context.mailbox.item#addhandlerasynceventtype-handler-options-callback) event to listen to changes in the appointment time when it is being created / edited, but this will only be triggered as long as the add-in is running.

We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our [user-voice page](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback?category_id=131778). Please add your request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered when we go through our planning process.

Comment: Isn't there any way that I can activate a subscription to notifications from the add-in and point it to an external script that will always be running on my server?

Comment: Which notifications are you talking about here? The only notifications available for add-ins to consume are the events listed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/objectmodel/preview-requirement-set/office#eventtype-string). As long as the add-in is running, you can subscribe to these events and push them to your backend. But there is no way to do this today when the add-in has stopped running - you cannot listen to them from your server directly.

Comment: However, outside of the add-in, you can use the [Outlook Notifications REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/api/version-2.0/notify-rest-operations) to subscribe to mailbox change notifications from a client-side web service.

Comment: How would I go about doing that? Do I subscribe directly from my web service or can I do it from my Add-In?

Comment: You can do it from either, but if you run it from the add-in, you're only limited to the time the add-in is running on the taskpane. You can look into the documentation for more details.

Comment: I'm interesting in subscribing to the Outlook Notifications REST API from a custom web-server and notify an outlook add-in about these changes when it's running.

Does the outlook add-in browser support the [Push API](https://www.w3.org/TR/push-api/)?